# Phpmyadmin Session Start error on last version

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've updated Phpmyadmin from 4.4.1 version to 4.4.2 version and started to get this error:

> Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#101  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_bsv20h8gq58qq1ep33qbfrb7r62jtksi,
>   O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/session.inc.php#101: session_start()
>   ./libraries/common.inc.php#349: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
>   ./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

This happened on two different machines with Centos 6.6 installed.
The serber have Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4 and Nginx as reverse proxy.

Answer (score 40):

In my case, I was running nginx primarily so needed to chown the sessions directory to nginx for user and group... (By default, the session folder was in the apache group).

```
chown nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

Then force refresh the phpMyAdmin page and the session permission related errors are resolved.

And if existing sessions, the contents too:-

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

Answer (score 16):

I know that this is a very old question, but I resolve the problema just with this line:

```
chmod 777 to /var/lib/php/session
```

My server details, CentOS 6, provider vultr.com

Comment: Mode 777 is rarely the right choice because it defeats security considerations that the application and the system depend on.

Comment: chmod 770 /var/lib/php/session
Works well.

Comment: This saved my time.

Comment: On Ubuntu: `chmod -R 777  /var/lib/php/sessions`.

Answer (score 4):

Phpmyadmin provide config for this case.

1. open config.inc.php file
2. add the phpmyadmin session directory config

> $cfg['SessionSavePath'] = '/tmp';

phpmyadmin/doc/config.rst

```
config:option:: $cfg['SessionSavePath']
:type: string
:default: ``''``

Path for storing session data (`session\_save\_path PHP parameter
<https://secure.php.net/session_save_path>`_).

warning::

This folder should not be publicly accessible through the webserver,
otherwise you risk leaking private data from your session.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had same issue on phpMyAdmin 4.4.3 cased by SELinux.

First of all check if you fit to server requirements http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html

Second, allow SELinux use PHP session:

```
grep php /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
semodule -i mypol.pp
```

and change PHP `session.save_path` permissions to `root:root`:

```
chown -R root:root /var/lib/php/session
chown -R root:root /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your php.ini file, specifically the "session" section.

```
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

If your using memcache you would probably have something like the following:

```
session.save_path = '127.0.0.1:11211'
```

By default it should look be a line like the following:

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

When copying a php.ini config from one server to another I ran into this issue where the other server was not using memcache for sessions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution postged by zigojacko, for PHP 7.1 I needed the following command:

```
chown nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/7.1/session
```

On Amazon Linux EC2 instance running Nginx.